# Max current draw from a UK Phone Line?

Tags: power, telephone

Reading a question on SuperUser where someone received an electric shock from a modem made me curious, how much power can a phone line provide?

(I'm not looking to do anything dodgy like try to power something, this is just out of curiously/amusement; in the UK phone lines operate at ~50v (up to 100 with an incoming call) enough to overcome the resistance of human skin in the right conditions. 10mA would give a nasty shock but 100-200mA has a high chance of fatality - in theory could someone actually be *electrocuted* by a phone line?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This source](http://www.cycom.co.uk/howto/bttelephone40macurrentsource.html) states that BT provides 40mA when the phone is off the hook.

[This other source](http://www.epanorama.net/circuits/telephone_ringer.html) talks about the expectations of the ringer circuit:

- less than or equal to 5mA draw at 35V/25Hz ring signal
- less than or equal to 10.5mA draw at 75V/25Hz ring signal

[PowerDsine's](http://www.microsemi.com/datasheets/pcr-sin06series.pdf) North America ring module generator appears to be limited to 3W, so I would expect the PSTN provider's capabilities to be similar. This signal gets shorted out when the phone goes on-hook, so the source can't be too stiff.

Comment: So no scaring my family with terrible tales of killer telephones then ;D. Very definitive answer, Thank You!