# How to draw current from a telephone line?

Tags: dc, low-power, telephone

My landline phone comes with a lcd display caller id and clock.
Even if I remove the 2 AA 1.5V batteries, the lcd still shows time even if I'm not busy on a call.
The lcd has no other source of power as is turns off when I disconnect the line.
I'd like to power up a 1.5V quartz analog clock using the phone line.
Is that possible?
Any circuit suggestions welcome. 
Thanks.

Edit:
The phone line has had no failures, at least since 2005, since they switched to fibre optic from copper wires.
And it's not illegal in India to connect low voltage devices like caller ID, tape recorders aka call recorders, answering machines and external ringers to the phone line, or so says the govt. owned company.
I'm crazy, officially:-P 
But has anyone got circuit diagrams?

Answer (score 5):

See [Max current draw from a UK Phone Line?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/14454/max-current-draw-from-a-uk-phone-line?rq=1) , [Using a telephone cable to power up a light blub](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/20410/using-a-telephone-cable-to-power-up-a-light-blub?rq=1)

You get up to 40ma at 50 volts, varying quite a lot when it rings. With a suitable buck converter you could probably power the clock, but it's not reccomended (and in some regions with state run telecoms may be illegal to connect unapproved equipment)

Answer (score 5):

> I'd like to power up a 1.5V quartz analog clock using the phone line.
>   Is that possible? Any circuit suggestions welcome.

It is possible and it's very likely to work. In the UK, BS6305:1992 was the standard that had to be met.

It allowed (now obsolete) a small current to be drawn when the line is inactive and from memory it was about (or less than 50uA). This is perfectly usable for a low power clock. Things have changes since I designed analogue phones but drawing a small current is still feasible.

However, given that a small coin battery would probably keep a clock going for at least a year (if not 5 years) why on earth would anyone go to all the trouble of interfacing it to a telephone line? Don't get me wrong, it's not a difficult circuit to do but why bother?

Every now and then it's bound to get disconnected (and reset to 12:00). OK, maybe to overcome this you can use a battery to keep the clock ticking over. But that defeats the whole object of having it powered from the telephone line. Right?

Time would be better spent designing a clock that would last ten years from said battery. Maybe I'm missing the point?

Comment: Batteries are a pain.  If their usage is unavoidable, or if they can be expected to last for the useful lifetime of the device (without being the limiting factor of the device lifetime) they're okay, but if a device can get by without them, that's often desirable.

Comment: @supercat I agree in general but for a circuit that probably needs to consume about a microamp or so with the liklihood that someone with a vacuum cleaner is going to knock out the line connection and therefore lose the functionality of the device I don't think having it line-powered makes much sense.

Comment: Note that the amount of current available (and to some extent the bias voltage) varies by territory and standard. In the US, you can draw a significant amount -- perhaps 50 mA? Meanwhile, in Scandinavia, the available/allowed draw is 5 mA. I remember this because long ago, an acquaintance tried to import a modem that was powered by jack power from the US, and it wouldn't work right for this reason.

Note that regulations even in the US state that "not actively communicating" devices should present a 5 MOhm impedance!

Comment: @JonWatte You can't draw 50mA from any telephone line without the exchange registering you have gone "off-hook". 5mA maybe but not 50mA.

Comment: @Andyaka: I certainly agree that it's desirable for a device to have a means of keeping time through short interruptions.  The question is whether it's better to have a battery, or better to use line power along with a cap that's good for an hour or so.  Note also that the it may be possible for the micro that operates the clock to do things like dial the phone, but phone operation should not require a battery to be installed.  Also, using a battery may require a means of disconnecting battery terminals from the phone line when the compartment is open (extra cost).

Comment: @supercat The OP's question is "I'd like to power up a 1.5V quartz analog clock using the phone line. Is that possible? Any circuit suggestions welcome". I didn't see anything about using the micro to dial numbers.

Comment: @Andyaka: Hmm... I'll agree that for a one-off thing, it's better not to tie into phone lines unnecessarily.  I'd been thinking in terms of designing a phone as a product with a built-in clock; in that scenario, it would make sense to use one phone-powered controller for everything.

Answer (score 3):

I made an experiment drawing power off the phone line and I discovered that when I draw more than 8-10 mA the phone goes ready to dial. I made a circuit that only draws 5 mA from the phone line regulated for charging a miniature .5F capacitor (super Cap). I only want to save the memory of the phone but in my case the display is always on. I hope this helps you.

Good luck.

Comment: Can you share the circuit? After all, that's what the original question is about.

Comment: Hi Dave i live in mexico and i don´t know the phone rules since the most rich men in the world is the owner of TELMEX if the contract don´t take care about , i understand that it is permisible, perhaps if i´am out of the law let me know please.